# Only show Wordpress comments when the user has posted their own comment

Tags: php, wordpress, function, comments

I'm running WordPress site and I need to adjust commenting option. I want any comments for post be hidden for user until this user has posted his own comment. If user is logged out, everything is hidden except login link. If user is logged in - comment form is visible but not comments.

What I got so far:

```
<?php

       if ( post_password_required() ) {
    return;
}
?>

<div id="comments" class="comments-area">

    <?php
    if ( have_comments() ) :
        ?>
        
        <?php

        the_comments_pagination(
            array(
                'prev_text'          => '<span class="screen-reader-text">' . __( 'Previous page', 'spoort' ) . '</span><i class="long-arrow-left" ></i>',
                'next_text'          => '<span class="screen-reader-text">' . __( 'Next page', 'spoort' ) . '</span><i class="long-arrow-right"></i>',
                'before_page_number' => '<span class="meta-nav screen-reader-text">' . __( 'Page', 'spoort' ) . ' </span>',
            )
        );
    endif;

    if ( ! comments_open() && get_comments_number() ) :
        echo '<p class="no-comments">' . esc_html_e( 'Comments are closed.', 'spoort' ) . '</p>';
    endif;
    comment_form();
        ?>
    
    <?php if ( is_user_logged_in() ) { ?>
            <ol class="comment-list">
        <?php
        wp_list_comments(
            array(
                'style'       => 'ol',
                'avatar_size' => 48,
                'short_ping'  => true,
            )
        );
        ?>
        </ol>
</div>
        <?php } else { ?>
<?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

The code you supplied looks like it's trying to do things in the wrong order and/or in the wrong places.  For example, `if ( have_comments() ) :` will display the pager, but you have that outside of the logic for whether comments should be displayed or not, so it's very possible to have someone see a pager but no comments, which is not good.

The code you gave is a little unclear, but I believe you want the following:

```
<?php

if ( post_password_required() ) {
    return;
}
?>

<?php
$display_comments = false;

if(comments_open()) {
    if(is_user_logged_in()) {
        ?>
        <div id="comments" class="comments-area">

        <?php
        //Go through all the comments on the post.
        foreach(get_comments() as $current_comment) {
            if($current_comment->comment_author == get_current_user_id()) {
                $display_comments = true;
            }
        }


        if(have_comments() && $display_comments) {
            the_comments_pagination(
                array(
                    'prev_text'          => '<span class="screen-reader-text">' . __( 'Previous page', 'spoort' ) . '</span><i class="long-arrow-left" ></i>',
                    'next_text'          => '<span class="screen-reader-text">' . __( 'Next page', 'spoort' ) . '</span><i class="long-arrow-right"></i>',
                    'before_page_number' => '<span class="meta-nav screen-reader-text">' . __( 'Page', 'spoort' ) . ' </span>',
                )
            );
            comment_form();

            <ol class="comment-list">
            <?php
            wp_list_comments(
                array(
                    'style'       => 'ol',
                    'avatar_size' => 48,
                    'short_ping'  => true,
                )
            );
            ?>
            </ol>
            <?php
        } else {
            comment_form();
        }

        ?>
        </div>
        <?php
    }


}








if(!comments_open() || !get_comments_number()) {
    echo '<p class="no-comments">' . esc_html_e( 'Comments are closed.', 'spoort' ) . '</p>';
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answer. However, I tried your code, I had to change $display_comments to true, otherwise I couldn't see comments even if I'm logged in. It works great, but it doesn't do what I really want. I want to show comments only for users who has logged in and has posted a comment. I tried adding functions from another file, but it doesn't want to work the way I want. I have a codes which could help, but not sure how to add it to the current file. 
`<?php if ( '0' == $comment->comment_approved ) : ?>`

Comment: I would recommend dumping the values in the foreach loop (`echo '<pre>'; print_r($current_comment); echo '</pre>';` as well as `echo get_current_user_id();`).  It's possible there's a mis-match there that I missed...  Maybe `$current_comment->comment_author` is the username and not the user's ID, in which case you'll need to derive username from `get_current_user_id()` before comparing that to `$current_comment->comment_author`